# VBA is not looping my for loop and the format for date/time did not change

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change the excel format from commas to a decimal point, however, when i tried to run my vba code, it skips from "For j=3 To LastCol" to End Sub. Why is it so? Furthermore, it didnt change the format for my range A1 to 1/12/2020 9:00:00 am.

```
Sub checkformat()
    Dim OriginalText As String
    Dim CorrectedText As String
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long
    LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Worksheets("RawData").Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(LastRow, 1)).Select
    Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(LastRow, 1)).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm"
    
    For j = 3 To LastCol
        For i = 3 To LastRow
            OriginalText = Worksheets("RawData").Cells(i, j).Value
            CorrectedText = Replace(OriginalText, ",", ".")
            Worksheets("RawData").Cells(i, j).Value = CorrectedText
        Next i
    Next j
End sub
```

My original text always occurs on the third row of each column

Comment: Is `LastCol` returning the number you expect? It needs to be 3 or more.

Comment: No while running the code, VBA just runs the line "For j=3..." and to End Sub

Comment: If you step through with F8 what number is LastCol giving you?

Comment: It gave me End sub

Comment: ...you're not understanding. Underneath your `LastCol` line put `Msgbox LastCol` and run the code. What number does it give?

Comment: It gave me "1".

Comment: You fetch `LastCol` and `LastRow` from ActiveSheet, not from sheet `RawData`

Comment: So in row 1 you only have something in the first column? To find the last column you need to use the row that actually has the last column in it. Also, what FunThomas just said.

Comment: My table starts at row 2. Row 2 is the header. The conversion from commas to dot starts at column 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

EDIT: I've updated the LastCol line to look in Row 2 instead. You have it looking in row 1 and if there isn't anything in the columns in row 1 it will just return a 1. You need to look for the last column in the appropriate row.

```
Sub checkformat()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim OriginalText As String, CorrectedText As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("RawData")
    LastCol = ws.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'This should be a 2 if this is where your headers are. The 2 is the row number your looking
    LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(3, 1), ws.Cells(LastRow, 1)).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm"
    
    For j = 3 To LastCol
        For i = 3 To LastRow
            OriginalText = ws.Cells(i, j).Value
            CorrectedText = Replace(OriginalText, ",", ".")
            ws.Cells(i, j).Value = CorrectedText
        Next i
    Next j
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, it have the same problem as my original code

Comment: Which row is column 55 in? And is it in the RawData sheet?

Comment: Ya, my RawData sheet contains 55 columns, the conversion from commas to decimal point starts from col 3. The numberformat line didnt work too

Comment: What **ROW** is there 55 columns in? Your checking in row 1. Should it be checking row 2 (has the headers) or row 3 (has the data)?

Comment: Row 2 is the header so the data starts at row 3. There're more than 7000 rows in each columns. I should check from row 3 onwards

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! Just for clarification, i should always start from the header and not the data is it?

Comment: Have a look at my edit and try it. You say more than 7000 rows with 55 columns so that's quite a lot to do with the looping. There are other better ways to do this for this much data. I put `ScreenUpdating` to false as well to help with it.

Comment: You need to look in the row that has the most columns in it. The function is `Cells(RowNumber, ColumnNumber)`. So whatever you put as the row number, that is the row it will use to find the last column. You put a 1 but your 55 columns is row 2 (Usually using the headers is best as data can potentially have gaps).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in add value to variables, cells is by default property of activesheet if you didnt write otherwise.

```
LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

then next you change sheet

```
Worksheets("RawData").Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(LastRow, 1)).Select
```

if columns and rows counter should be in worksheet RawData then change variables to

```
LastCol = Worksheets("RawData").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow = Worksheets("RawData").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

and then should work fine

you can also assume some value to check max values of column and rows counters like below

```
Sub RowsColumnsCounter()
Dim i_lr As Integer, i_tempLr As Integer, i_lc As Integer, i_tempLc As Integer, i_assumption As Integer

i_lc = 0
i_lr = 0
i_assumption = 20

For i = 1 To i_assumption
    For j = 1 To i_assumption
        i_tempLc = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        i_tempLr = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp).Row
        If i_tempLc > i_lc Then i_lc = i_tempLc:   i_tempLc = 0
        If i_tempLr > i_lr Then i_lr = i_tempLr: i_tempLr = 0
    Next j
Next i

MsgBox "last row is: " & i_lr & vbCrLf & "last column is: " & i_lc
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, i did what you told me. For eg, LastCol = Worksheets("RawData").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column when i write MsgBox LastCol it shows me the value one instead. Shouldnt my last column be 55 instead?

Comment: i dont know how much columns you have. Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column will count all not empty columns in row 1 of this sheet

Comment: ho to loop it such that it count all 7000 rows of data i had?

Comment: full code posted by Simon should work. you can add to set ws = THISWORKBOOK.worksheets("RawData"). lastcol u should count on row where you have headers or first data and rows u should count on column with longest data